# HHVM with nginx don't run php from subfolders

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I have working setup with nginx and hhvm. This is part of my config with rules, that uses in each request (got from debug log):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 502 = @fallback;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Then I have simple site:

```
root
  index.php // echo 'this is index'
  sub
    index.php  // echo 'this is sub'
```

Now if I load `example.com` I will see `this is index`. Right.

But `example.com/sub` - I still see `this is index` instead `this is sub`

Why so? Please help.

Btw, if I will use php-fpm:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Everything is normal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe solved,... Or not !

You should have :

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

instead of

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root;
```

with php-fpm and hhvm.